# Javascript variable passing

Tags: javascript, variables

Can anyone help me with my project? How will I be able to call the textfield details in javascript?

```
function AddPushpin()
{
    var shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, map.GetCenter());
    shape.SetTitle(**//it should be coming from a textfield//**);
    shape.SetDescription('This is shape number '+pinid);
    pinid++;
    map.AddShape(shape);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

document.getElementById('myTextElementsId').value

Answer (score 3):

```
<textfield id="shapeTitle"></textfield>

---- // -----

document.getElementById('shapeTitle').value
```

where 'shapeTitle' should correspond to the ID of the element you need the value of.

Comment: is it possible that I can upload for example a picture through this?

I mean, is this the same code?